# How to deserialize array of objects with no name?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So I have array of object being POSTed to my view with shape like this:

```js
[{"id": 5, "is_read": true},
 {"id": 6, "is_read": false}]
```

I want to find a way of deserializing that in my DRF serializer. It is possible to have nested serializers when your array has name, that is, is like this: `"arrayName": []` instead of just like this: `[]`.

With nested serializers I could write something like this:

```py
class MarkReadItemDeserializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Message.objects.all())
    is_read = serializers.BooleanField()


class MarkReadDeserializer(serializers.Serializer):
    arrayName = MarkReadItemDeserializer(many=True)
```

Now this obviously doesn't work in my case because my array is not named `arrayName`.

Any idea how I could go about this?

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: why not using `MarkReadItemDeserializer` directly from your view with `many=True`? it should do the trick

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is not yet written.

Comment: @MahmoudAdel How do you include a serializer directly in a view with `many=True`?

Comment: add your view to the question so we can suggest something based on your view

Comment: @jafarlii: wel the view can JSON parse it and then pass the content to the serializer.